# Workflow for 2.5D pixel art texturing

Tags: texturing, uv, 2d, pixel-art

I'm working on a game that is supposed to look like Octopath Traveler. So I need 3D models with pixel art textures. But I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the texturing part.

[image: octopath example]

I can unwrap the model, export it and paint a pixel art texture on photoshop. I'm sure that would work, but from my understanding, that's mostly used for unique textures (like characters and such). But, for example, let's say I'm working on a "brick castle texture", that is supposed to be used all over the place. I might use the bricks for the castle facade, interior, a bridge nearby, a pillar, etc. If it was just one texture though, it would also be easy, I just make a tileable brick texture and apply it. But I need more than just one image - there should be painted windows, details, like in the image below. For this, I believe the correct approach is to use texture maps/trim sheets, right? There's an example of what Octopath uses below.

[image: Octopath Traveler texture map example]

Ok, I can do that. But how do I map my unwrapped UVs to something like that? If I manually change my faces to fit into that texture, it'll look stretched. And I won't be able to maintain consistent texel density (or pixel size, let's say). If I use something to set the texel density, then I have no guarantee my UVs will match with the drawing in the texture. And like... let's say I have a brick sample that is sized like in the image above. Do I have to model with that size in mind? What if I just wanna fill a big wall with that texture? What if the face is a bit smaller and won't fit? I had the impression I could just drag and drop a brick texture and have it fill whatever face. But maybe I'm wrong and this is absolutely not how it's done? Or is it? I'm confused. And even then, what's the big idea, to manually drag each face manually to the correct place? I have no idea what this workflow is supposed to be like.

Just making it more visual and clear: how do I take this

[image: UV unwrap]

And make it so this is a different type of brick

[image]

And these having pixel art windows

[image]

While using a modular texture map or trim sheet to use them across multiple objects. With the added detail that it's pixel art, and that the pixels need to stay at a consistent size. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding everything and this is supposed to be done in a completely different way?

Sorry for such a long question that might demand a long answer. I'd strongly appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance!